# Adding a UISegmentedControl to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

How do I add a UISegmentedControl to a UITableView?
Similar to the image found here:
http://cdn.imore.com/sites/imore.com/files/styles/large/public/field/image/2012/08/iHomework-for-iPhone-managing-assignments-and-tasks.jpg

I would like to have a UISegmentedControl that sticks underneath the navigation bar.

This is what I've tried so far:

In my viewDidLoad method, I've created a UISegmentedControl

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil]];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(50, 0, 220, 100);
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlHasChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

However, the segmented control overlaps with the tableview itself.

**EDIT**

Additionally,I would like to create this uisegmentedcontrol fully programmatically as I don't want to use a nib file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = segmentedControl;
```

If you want it to obey your width and height properly though enclose your segmentedControl in a UIView first as the tableView likes to mangle your view a bit to fit the width.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: However, is there a way to pin the segmented control underneath without it moving with the rest of the table? Thanks!

Comment: +1 Do you know if/how this can be done in Xcode 5.1.1 (i.e. in Interface Builder)?

Comment: You should be able to drag a UIView onto a tableview and it will add it as a header.

Comment: @wayway did you find a way?